# Is there a simpler way to find state coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I am currently in the process of my very first project for JS. I am creating an interactive map that will display markers on each state within the US. By using Leaflet.jS, I have achieved this by coding in every state in the US. Starting in alphabetical order, I wrote the name of each state along with the coordinates.

Here is an Example of my code:

```
    const stateInfo = [
  {
    state: 'Alabama',
    coords: [32.806671, -86.79113],
    abbreviation: 'al',
  },
  {
    state: 'Alaska',
    coords: [61.370716, 152.404419],
    abbreviation: 'ak',
  },
```

Is there a simpler way to do this, instead of adding many lines of code for each state?

Comment: You could use Google's Geocoding service: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Google's Geocoding service. See [the documentation here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple). And here is [a sample that will `console.log` state coordinates](https://jsfiddle.net/adelriosantiago/rw078n4o/) (note that need a Google Maps key to make the snippet work).

Another simple way to do it is to simply use this JSON data: https://gist.github.com/meiqimichelle/7727723.